# NServiceBus - How to use NSB to handle events from large population of devices

Tags: nservicebus

Sorry if this question is a little naive

We have a large number of devices (> 100,000) sending events into our host, and we'd like different customer applications to be able to receive events from specific devices

A concrete example would be temperature readings, and one customer application may want readings from all devices in a geographic region, whilst another may want readings from all devices that are installed in specific equipment (e.g. chilled food areas), but over many geographical areas
Yet another customer application would only be interested in devices they manufactured
i.e. these would be overlapping 'sets' of devices

Maybe this is just one example of the 'Internet of Things' (IoT)?

I believe the pub/sub method in NSB uses 'message types' to identify the destination subscriptions - but I suspect these messages are all the same type

I believe that, assuming I handled the routing myself, I could use bus.send

But is this the right way to go with NSB?

Are there any articles or documents that illustrate this type of architecture?

N.B. we currently have a solution using persistent MSMQ with a 'hand rolled' routing solution (the implementation is no longer appropriate - see below) - so there is some pressure to 'evolve' that solution, instead of adopting a better solution like NSB

Why is it no longer appropriate? - lots of reasons, but chiefly it was implemented to route messages by type (intention was to have different services consume different types)
But we also allowed routing by 'group' (a collection of devices), and this is how it's currently used - but it's a manual configuration, quite awkward now that we have thousands of devices, and large numbers of customer applications (100+) which need their own 'group' of devices, but now want to 'share' some of their devices to other customer applications as well
It was written custom code using MSMQ (and dotnet 1.0 - it was our first dot net project! - so it's not done too badly)
But as we're looking to re-write this, it made sense to look at NSB

I guess part of the problem is that I haven't found a 'pattern' that fits what we're trying to do - so it makes it harder to explain what it is
But, given the advent of the 'Internet oF Things' - I was hoping this was a more common problem than maybe it really is?

Comment: Can you expand upon how the implementation is no longer appropriate?  This will help define the approach.

Comment: Edited original post to expand on existing solution

Comment: It sounds like you need content-based routing on a subscription-level.  There is a `IPublishMessages` interface and perhaps you could provide a custom implementation that removes subscribers based on the content.  I am not a NServiceBus expert so perhaps someone could indicate whether such a solution would be possible/useful.

Comment: I'm currently thinking that if I have to implement myself some form of  routing based on content to specific subscribers, then I may well use 'point to point' messaging instead - I don't see what benefit pub/sub would be giving me in that case

Answer (score 1):

Having built these kinds of systems before, one of the things you need to take into account is that any UI the user is looking at will not be able to refresh fast enough to reflect the rate at which real world changes are happening.

The design needs to lean on an in-memory model that is updated as the real world changes are processed. From there, the simplest solution is to have the UI thread poll that model and then render the current state.

If users will want to be able to change the filters they're using at runtime, you'll need to have the client still hold all the info so that you have enough history for the user to see. For clarity, that means that the client doesn't filter the data based on what the user is current looking at - it needs to receive and process everything.

At the rates you're talking about (1M+ msgs/min = 15k msgs/s), you're not going to want to process that on every client. Instead, you'll want some kind of Common Operational Picture Server (COPS) which will aggregate the data from all the devices.

If the number of clients you need to support isn't that large, you could just have them poll the COPS - that would be simplest.

In any case, if using NServiceBus or not, you'll want to avoid transactional/durable messaging to achieve the rates you're talking about. I don't think that MSMQ will scale high enough for you even if using non-durable messages - RabbitMQ will probably be a better choice for you.

If you need to perform any kind of logic on higher level entities whose state is built off of the data coming from multiple sensors, then things get more complicated. I wrote an article about this some time back: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569749.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: "In any case, if using NServiceBus or not, you'll want to avoid transactional/durable messaging to achieve the rates you're talking about"

Comment: "In any case, if using NServiceBus or not, you'll want to avoid transactional/durable messaging to achieve the rates you're talking about."  Yes - we'd already realised that, with our experience of MSMQ & durable messageing  We're considering storing the incoming data separate to the messaging, using distributed storage  Thanks for the pointer to COPS - I'll go away & research that - it's exactly the type of info I was after

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a class Pub/Sub type scenario.  If you are starting to have similar data be shown to different consumers it would be better to have the consumers subscribe to all messages and let  the consumer drop the ones it does not care about.  Configuration stays with the consumer.

With NSB you can do that a couple of ways, either have different message types and have each consumer subscribe just to the ones it cares about, or just have each consumer receive all messages and only handle the messages it cares about.  The downside to the latter is it creates more traffic, but this may not be a problem in your situation.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the response  _The downside to the latter is it creates more traffic, but this may not be a problem in your situation._  Unfortunately I think it will be  We're expecting each device to send a message every minute, so we're lcurrently ooking at 100,000+ messages per minute, and if we assume 100 subscribers, then that's a lot of traffic, and the aim is to be able scale up to 1 million devices